# Azure Stream Analytics: How to use two Azure Machine Learning Function

Tags: t-sql, azure-stream-analytics

I am using two Azure Machine Learning Function in Stream Analytics but it seems like only one can be used per query. How can I split it into two queries?

> The streaming job failed: Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Multiple AML web service functions used in subquery. A query step can contain no more than one AML function. Please split the step into multiple steps.

```
WITH subquery as (
    SELECT
        id as id,
        deviceId as deviceId,
        username as username,
        try_cast(localtime as datetime) as localtime,
        AC as AC, FM as FM, UC as UC, 
        DL as DL, DS as DS, DP as DP,
        LB as LB, ASTV as ASTV, MSTV as MSTV,
        ALTV as ALTV, MLTV as MLTV, Width as Width,
        Min as Min, Max as Max, Nmax as Nmax,
        Nzeros as Nzeros, Mode as Mode, Mean as Mean,
        Median as Median, Variance as Variance, Tendency as Tendency,
        rms,fmed,fpeak,sample_entropy,
        EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime,
        Distress(AC,FM,UC,DL,DS,DP,1,LB,ASTV,MSTV,ALTV,MLTV,
            Width,Min,Max,Nmax,Nzeros,Mode,Mean,Median,Variance,
            Tendency,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) as resultFHR,
        Labour("",1,1,1,"",rms,fmed,fpeak,sample_entropy,"","") as resultUC
    FROM
        iot
    )

SELECT
    id as id,
    deviceId as deviceId,
    username as username,
    localtime as localtime,
    AC as AC, FM as FM, UC as UC, 
    DL as DL, DS as DS, DP as DP,
    LB as LB, ASTV as ASTV, MSTV as MSTV,
    ALTV as ALTV, MLTV as MLTV, Width as Width,
    Min as Min, Max as Max, Nmax as Nmax,
    Nzeros as Nzeros, Mode as Mode, Mean as Mean,
    Median as Median, Variance as Variance, Tendency as Tendency,
    EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime,
    resultFHR.[classes] as distress,
    resultFHR.[probabilities] as distressProbability,
    resultUC.[classes] as labour,
    resultUC.[probabilities] as labourProbability
INTO
    sql
FROM
    subquery


SELECT
    *
INTO
    c2d
FROM
    subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split it up into 2 separate steps. Eg:

WITH subquery1 as ( SELECT id as id, deviceId as deviceId, username as username, try_cast(localtime as datetime) as localtime, AC as AC, FM as FM, UC as UC, DL as DL, DS as DS, DP as DP, LB as LB, ASTV as ASTV, MSTV as MSTV, ALTV as ALTV, MLTV as MLTV, Width as Width, Min as Min, Max as Max, Nmax as Nmax, Nzeros as Nzeros, Mode as Mode, Mean as Mean, Median as Median, Variance as Variance, Tendency as Tendency, rms,fmed,fpeak,sample_entropy, EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime, **Distress(AC,FM,UC,DL,DS,DP,1,LB,ASTV,MSTV,ALTV,MLTV, Width,Min,Max,Nmax,Nzeros,Mode,Mean,Median,Variance, Tendency,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) as resultFHR** FROM iot )

WITH subquery as ( SELECT id as id, deviceId as deviceId, username as username, try_cast(localtime as datetime) as localtime, AC as AC, FM as FM, UC as UC, DL as DL, DS as DS, DP as DP, LB as LB, ASTV as ASTV, MSTV as MSTV, ALTV as ALTV, MLTV as MLTV, Width as Width, Min as Min, Max as Max, Nmax as Nmax, Nzeros as Nzeros, Mode as Mode, Mean as Mean, Median as Median, Variance as Variance, Tendency as Tendency, rms,fmed,fpeak,sample_entropy, EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime, **Labour("",1,1,1,"",rms,fmed,fpeak,sample_entropy,"","") as resultUC** FROM iot )

SELECT id as id, deviceId as deviceId, username as username, localtime as localtime, AC as AC, FM as FM, UC as UC, DL as DL, DS as DS, DP as DP, LB as LB, ASTV as ASTV, MSTV as MSTV, ALTV as ALTV, MLTV as MLTV, Width as Width, Min as Min, Max as Max, Nmax as Nmax, Nzeros as Nzeros, Mode as Mode, Mean as Mean, Median as Median, Variance as Variance, Tendency as Tendency, EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime, **resultFHR.[classes] as distress, resultFHR.[probabilities] as distressProbability** INTO sql FROM subquery1

SELECT id as id, deviceId as deviceId, username as username, localtime as localtime, AC as AC, FM as FM, UC as UC, DL as DL, DS as DS, DP as DP, LB as LB, ASTV as ASTV, MSTV as MSTV, ALTV as ALTV, MLTV as MLTV, Width as Width, Min as Min, Max as Max, Nmax as Nmax, Nzeros as Nzeros, Mode as Mode, Mean as Mean, Median as Median, Variance as Variance, Tendency as Tendency, EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime, **resultUC.[classes] as labour, resultUC.[probabilities] as labourProbability** INTO sql FROM subquery2

Comment: it would not work. there is an error near second with.